# Filter a Laravel collection without returning a copy

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to remove items in my laravel relation collection by matching on certain values. Questions have a one-to-many relationship with Answers.

*Before you ask, these removals need to be done in memory and stored to the DB later (so we can do some stuff with validation.)*

So, I'm working with the Collection that the relationship object gives me:

```
$this->answers->filter(function($answer) use ($answer_ids_to_remove){
  return !in_array($answer['id'], $answer_ids_to_remove);
});
```

However Collection::filter returns a copy, and doesn't modify the existing collection. So I tried this:

```
$this->answers = $this->answers->filter(function($answer) use ($answer_ids_to_remove){
  return !in_array($answer['id'], $answer_ids_to_remove);
});
```

However I think this assignment removes the link between the collection and the relationship itself, because I started getting No Such Column errors when saving the model:

```
General error: 1 no such column: answers (SQL: update "questions" set "answers" = {"1":{"id":"72","question_id":"117","text":"Answer 2","order":"1"},"2":{"id":"73","question_id":"117","text":"Answer 3","order":"2"},"3":{"text":"Answer 4","question_id":117,"order":3}}, "updated_at" = 2015-11-02 19:18:31 where "id" = 117)
```

The fact that it's trying to turn it into JSON suggests it no longer recognizes the one-to-many relationship, due to the assignment.

Can I run filter() on the original collection? Or is there a way to re-link the collection to the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `intersect` method on the collection like so:

```
foreach($answer_ids_to_remove as answer) {
    $this->answers->intersect($answer)
}
```

Instead of building an array of answers ids to remove use the collection itself.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-intersect

Comment: That looks like it would remove all but the first matching item on the first iteration, then on the next it would remove all the others. Plus, that also returns a copy of the array, without modifying the original. Am I missing something?

Comment: Never used `intersect` before actually and I miss read you question. Thought that you didn't want to modify the original collection. I am sorry. The only one I can see in the docs that do modify the collection is the `forget()` method, but it removes an item from the collection by its key